# Replication not working on generated columns in PostgreSQL 12.1

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-12

I am using below architecture for replication.

Master(Publication) Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.patient (
  pk int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  patientid int8 NOT NULL  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.fnGetPrimaryKey(pk, clientid)) STORED,
  firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  clientid int2 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_patient PRIMARY KEY (patientid));
```

Replica Identity:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX patient_replica_identity ON patient (patientid);
ALTER TABLE patient REPLICA IDENTITY USING INDEX patient_replica_identity;
```

Replica(Subscription) Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.patient (
    pk int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    patientid int8 NOT NULL  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.fnGetPrimaryKey(pk, clientid)) STORED,
    firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    clientid int2 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_patient PRIMARY KEY (patientid)
);
```

When I start the replication then system is throwing below error:

> ERROR:  publisher did not send replica identity column expected by the logical replication target relation "public.patient"

If I change the primary key patientid to `CONSTRAINT pk_patient PRIMARY KEY (clientid,pk)` then it will working fine.

I don't want to change subscription database's primary key.

Let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: That's [a bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/a9139c29-7ddd-973b-aa7f-71fed9c38d75%40minerva.info) - a fix has [been comitted](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6da7ccbd-4531-c876-3d74-7d2938ed8fb3%402ndquadrant.com) and will thus it show show up in the [next minor release](https://www.postgresql.org/developer/roadmap/)

Comment: I upgrade latest postgresql 12.1, but issue is not resolved yet. ERROR message has been changed : [publisher did not send replica identity column expected by the logical replication target relation "public.patient"]